# How to compare values within two List<List<CustomClass>> in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a 2048-type game where the gameboard grid is made up of a list of 4 other lists (each of which contain 4 Tiles).

Each time a move is made, the newGameboardGrid is saved in yet another list (so that removeLast can be called when a player wants to undo a move).

When a player swipes, I need to compare the newGameboardGrid grid with the previous one to see if any actual movement took place or if the tile values are still the same (as would happen if a player swiped in a direction where no movement was possible).

I tried this code:

```
if (newGameboardGrid == listOfGameboardGrids.last) {
// do something
}
```

It almost works in that it *is* comparing the <List<List< Tile>> from the new move with the <List<List< Tile>> of the last move, but the problem is that it never results in the two <List<List< Tile>> as being equal, even when all the tile values are identical. I believe it's because it is comparing hashcodes and/or other things.

[image: New Contents of Grid]

The Tile class has lots of stuff in it, but the thing I would like to compare is that int named "value".  Is it possible to compare only the "value" variable for these two <List<List< Tile>>?

Thanks in advance for any help! (And apologies if any of my terms are imprecise.)

Comment: Have you at least implemented some kind of comparison for the `Tile` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart list implementations do not override the `operator==` of `Object`, so they are only ever equal to themselves. The elements are not checked.

IF you want to compare the elements (and here, the elements of the list elements), you can use the [`Equality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/Equality-class.html) classes from `package:collection`:

```dart
const boardEquality = ListEquality(ListEquality(DefaultEquality()));
```

This creates a [`ListEquality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ListEquality-class.html) object which compares two lists of lists of elements by checking that they contain the same number of lists, which again contains the same number of equal elements. (I assume that `Tile` implements `operator==`).

You can the use it as: `if (boardEquality.equals(newGameboardGrid, listOfGameboardGrids.last)) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an extension method on your particular list type and make an `isEqual` method for that compares each `Tile`:

```dart
extension TileListComp on List<List<Tile>> {
  bool isEqual(List<List<Tile>> other) {
    if(this.length != other.length || this[0]?.length != other[0]?.length) {
      return false;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
      for(int y = 0; y < this[0].length; y++) {
        if(this[x][y] != other[x][y]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

If you have **not** implemented any kind of comparison for your `Tile` class, you will need to do so. I can advise if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've just watched some tutorial on extension method and I'm understanding the general concept, but I'm not sure how to implement. No, I haven't implemented any kind of comparison for the Tile class. Maybe I could make a for loop that goes through and takes the value from each tile in the newGameboardGrid <List<List<Tile>>> and stores it in a list of 16 numbers, then do the same for the previous move and then compare the two lists?

Comment: @Derence I already provided a method for nested list equality in my answer. You just need to implement equality in your `Tile` class.

Comment: @Derence What's the point of having a 2d array in addition to storing the x & y coordinate in your Tile class?